# loading image from disk to JSP page

Tags: java, image, jsp, desktop

I want to load group of image from a folder in my desktop to JSP page,
I tried to load it directly like:

```html
<img src="desktopPath/images/1.jpg" />
```

but it not loaded ! .. What i understood from searching that it couldn't !
can any one help me, How can i load them ?

I'm beginner in using JSP.

Comment: What does it display? A cross?

Comment: yes, as i remember a cross in the upper-left corner ..

Comment: It's not only a jsp issue. Is it a spring application? A spring boot? Do you have web.xml in which you specify static resources directory?

Comment: yeah i have, but how can i specify it?!